# how can i use core data to access an array saved in a different view controller?

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data

I am saving an array into core data in one viewcontroller, how can i access that array of entities in a different view controller? also how would i apply the attributes (in this case they are string) to labels in the other view controller?

Comment: Helps if you show the code you are having issues with.

Comment: i really haven't written much code for it, just trying to conceptualize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored in a database unrelated to any particular viewController, so that is no reason why it cannot be accessed from a different viewController.  In general you should use a fetchedResultsController.  A fetchedResutsController will do a fetch and then monitor core-data for changes.  So if an a object is deleted or added the array of fetchedObjects will automatically update.  This is a great feature, as accessing a core-data object that was deleted could lead to a crash.

Comment: Ive really only found how to do this with a tableView, i am only trying to get the core data linked up with a label and then go to the next saved word when the next button is pressed, any idea how to do this?